# NTLM Authentication works on one machine but not from another

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ntlm

This is giving me headeches, I have this code that works perfectly on two machines:

```
 CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
 cc.Add(
    uri,
    "NTLM",
    new NetworkCredential(@"MyDomain\MyUsername", "MyPassword"));
 request.Credentials = cc;
```

On a third one, NTLM fails with http code 401, I'm sure I have access since it works with different browsers* (Firefox, IE) on this same machine.

What could cause the problem?

*I used fiddler to be sure that the browsers use NTLM and they do.

Comment: Is your third machine using a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
 new NetworkCredential(@"MyDomain\MyUsername", "MyPassword"));
```

By

```
 new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MyDomain"));
```

Fixed the problem on the third machine... It's weird that the code behaves differently depending on the machine...

Answer (score 0):

In the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x2s2s6(v=vs.110).aspx
They write the following under 'Remarks':

'The supported values for authType are "NTLM", "Digest", "Kerberos", and "Negotiate".
Credentials added with this method are only valid for use with SMTP. This method does not work for HTTP or FTP protocols.'

I think maybe you're using different protocols than SMTP to make your credentials. The error code 401 is mostly generated through the HTTP.

Or you simple do not refer to an appropriate SMTP address. How to fix this issue.. I don't know, I can only try to identify the problem. Maybe your refering to a non-existing address.

Here, perhaps this will help: [HttpWebRequest 401 with NTLM Authenticiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263561/httpwebrequest-401-with-ntlm-authenticiation)